# Python Beautiful Soup, how to get a content of <script>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all information of coins from https://www.binance.com/en/

I have a very basic knowledge of HTML

```
<script nonce="2266e2ddf786c1ef22250edde36dae937ccbbe17">
        __NEXT_DATA__ = {
                    "tickers": {
                        "NULSBNB": {
                            "s": "NULSBNB",
                            "l": "0.13312",
                            "c": "0.13904",
                            "h": "0.16600",
                            "o": "0.13680",
                            "q": 5514.584306,
                            "v": "37908.30000",
                            "qa": "BNB",
                            "ba": "NULS",
                            "bn": "Nuls",
                            "tickSize": "0.00001",
                            "minTrade": 0.1
                        },
```

Apparently this is the information I need
Here's my code:

```
import requests
import bs4


URL = "https://www.binance.com/"

r = requests.get(url = URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')


contents = soup.find_all(script ='2266e2ddf786c1ef22250edde36dae937ccbbe17')
print(contents)
```

And it doesn't work.
How do I get a information for every coin? I need "s" and "l" most of all

Answer (score 1):

I would face the problem of *get a information for every coin* in a different way.
It can be easy to get the information from [Binance API](https://support.binance.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004492232-API-Frequently-Asked-Questions-FAQ-).
With one search I [found](https://github.com/binance-exchange/python-binance) a decent open source package for python.
Using for example this with a set of your coin symbols can do the trick.

*Note: I have not tested the package, that not supposed to be the answer.
Rather than using the API if it's available, so you don't need to scrape.*